# How can I import large amounts of GMail to Skydrive?

Tags: gmail, onedrive

I have about 100 GB of messages in my GMail account. What is easiest way to migrate the 100 GB GMails to Skydrive? There used to be an online software called *Trueswitch* that could do that, but it is no longer available. [yippiemove.com](http://yippiemove.com) is similar service, but they do not support IMAP.

I'm considering using this transfer service https://www.cloudhq.net/dropbox/backup/google_gmail/skydrive
Is this a feasible service to import 90GB of GMail to Skydrive ?

Are there any other solutions to importing 100GB of GMail to Skydrive?

Comment: Thanks Jamie Thomas. I know about http://blogs.office.com/2013/12/11/outlook-com-makes-it-even-easier-to-switch-from-gmail/  but problem is Outlook.com has storage limit 5GB so we signed up for 100GB Skydrive storage. Does that mean we have to do 2 step transfer- first import 5GB from gmail to outlook.com and then move the 5GB from outlook.com to skydrive  and then repeat again for every 5GB unti all 100GB gmail is imported to Skydrive? What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft recently launched a feature that allows you to easily migrate your Gmail account to Outlook.com (which I assume is what you mean since SkyDrive is the Microsoft equivalent of Google Drive).  Here is the blog post annoucing this:

http://blogs.office.com/2013/12/11/outlook-com-makes-it-even-easier-to-switch-from-gmail/

I use both services, but I can understand your desire to switch!

Answer (score 0):

Since December 2013 Google has been rolling out the ability to download your data from a number of google ervices including gmail.

The [Instructions are here](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/download-copy-of-your-gmail-and-google.html):

> You can download all of your mail and calendars or choose a subset of
>   labels and calendars. You can also download a single archive file for
>   multiple products with a copy of your Gmail, Calendar, Google+,
>   YouTube, Drive, and other Google data.

This is done at the account level nor the gamil level:

So go to:

1. account
2. Data tool
3. Select Data to download
4. Create an Archive
5. Then start selecting what you want to download.